# Xamarin OnPlatform - Duplicate Names

Tags: xamarin

I have the following code:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="StackLayout">
    <On Platform="iOS">
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry 
                StyleClass="LogOnEntry"
                x:Name="UserName"
```

and similar a similar block for Android.

When I compile for Android, I get the error:

CS0102 the type 'LogOnPage' already contains a definition for 'UserName'.

That's because it is called the same Name on both platforms.  I would have thought that when compiling, the OnPlatform tag would have supressed the other Name, leaving only one??

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Since there are the similar elements both in iOS and Android , you could set them as common part and use **OnPlatform** to set different properties(like color or font) .

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">


        <Entry x:Name="UserName">

            <Entry.FontSize>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                      iOS="20"
                      Android="22" />
            </Entry.FontSize>

        </Entry>

    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: The problem  is my whole StackLayout is different for each platform (due to problems on iOS with Frames in a ListView).  I may see if "nested" OnPlatform's work.

Comment: What is `problems on iOS with Frames in a ListView` ?Maybe we can solve it without using OnPlatform .

Comment: I have solved it using OnPlatform, that's why I have this problem.  A ListView containing Frames that contain text.  when scrolling down then up, the bit that was off screen corrupts (text over text).  Same code on Android is OK.

Comment: I've done it a different way now, so I am OK.  I may log the original problem as a separate ticket.

Comment: You could share your solution here , which will help more people who has similar issue .

Comment: My solution was to find a way that did not require OnPlatform

Comment: I have the same issue, I have different views for platforms, and I specify names for controls in the XAML, but they are declared twice in the .g file, so unable to compile