# Xamarin.Forms: add control (in XAML) based on Platform

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, layout, platform

I have this (simplified) layout in XAML using Xamarin Forms:

```
<controls:MyTabItemView>
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid>
            ......
                <controls:CustomButton x:Name="XYZ"/>
            ......
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</controls:TabItemView>
```

This is fine in iOS, but in Android, I do NOT want the ScrollView, the main container should be the Grid, so like:

```
<controls:MyTabItemView>
    <Grid>
         ......
            <controls:CustomButton x:Name="XYZ"/>
         ......
    </Grid>
</controls:TabItemView>
```

If I try to create 2 layout using the `<OnPlatform>` and `<On Platform="Android" / "iOS">` paradigm (basically duplicate all in XAML, but remove the `<ScrollView>` in the Android part), that almost works, but due to `XYZ` it will result in build error, as the `.g.cs` file will declare the `XYZ` twice. This is a known error, see: [Xamarin OnPlatform - Duplicate Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709934/xamarin-onplatform-duplicate-names)

So as I could not do in XAML, I tried to hack in xaml.cs, in the view constructor,

```
if (Xamarin.Forms.Device.RuntimePlatform == Xamarin.Forms.Device.Android)
{
    Children[0] = Children[0].Children[0];  //get rid of ScrollView
}
```

This won't compile as `Children` is `IReadOnlyList`.

Any suggestion, what is the best solution here, to NOT add the ScrollView in case of Android, but start with the Grid as the main container?

Thanks

Comment: Define two control templates, one for each platform. Then load the appropriate one as the content of a contentview. To avoid having to duplicate all the xaml, make a separate class for the inner part that is used on both. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template

Comment: Thanks, that's a possibility indeed. I hope it could be solved easier, but if not, will have a look at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the layout that was created, after `InitializeComponent();` you can do the replacement this way:

```cs
var topLayout = (ScrollView)Children[0];
Children.RemoveAt(0);
Children.Insert(0, topLayout.Children[0]);
```

This replaces the `ScrollView` with its first child.

Comment: Ok, so basically my `Children[0] = Children[0].Children[0];` idea, right?

Comment: Right, but with syntax that actually compiles! (I came back to the question later, and realized that there was a way to do what you attempted.)

Comment: Actually I implemented differently in the meanwhile (duplicated in the XAML, using OnPlatform, and choose different name for the controls Android<>iOS, and in the .xaml.cs code, I just work with the proper control), but your solution also works, so I will accept it.